# How do I activate Windows 7 for a different computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation

I bought Windows 7 Professional Retail which I installed on my laptop.  Now I've decided to move it to be on my desktop PC, so I uninstalled Windows from my laptop, restoring the original OS that came with the laptop (Vista Business), and installed Windows 7 on my desktop PC. The problem is that I cannot activate my copy of Windows 7 on the desktop PC.  Every time I try to activate it I get the error message:

> The product key you typed cannot be used to activate Windows on this computer

and the code of the error is:

> Code: 0xc004c008
>
> Description:
>   The activation server determined that the specified product key could not be used.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by calling the automated tool free phone number service for the country where I live and just followed the instructions.
Thank you all who tried to help me.

---

> 1. Press the `Windows Logo Key+R`. This will bring up the Run dialog box.
> 2. In the Open box, type `"slui 4"` and press OK. This will start the
>      manual activation wizard.
> 3. Select your Country in the drop down menu and click Next.
> 4. The wizard will display a Toll Free phone number. Leave the wizard open on the computer and call that phone number.

Answer (score 2):

This [Microsoft Support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938450) has information on the error code. It states under the heading for your error code:

> **Cause**
>   This issue may occur if the KMS key has exceeded the activation limit. KMS keys will activate up to 10 times on six different computers.
>
> **Workaround**
>   If you need more activation times, contact the PA Call Center.

It looks like you have to ring Microsoft Support.

Comment: I don't think exceeding the activation limit is the problem because this is the second time I try to acivate windows the first one was when I install it on my laptop and on that time it succeeded.

Comment: @Abdullah, it looks like Win7 activation is more sensitive than it should be, http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7install/thread/787b3388-f21b-44a0-98db-42fea894474b.  Try doing what Ronnie Vernon indicates in the link above.

Comment: @hyperslug: Thank very much, I solved the problem by calling the automated Toll free phone number for my country. WOW.. What a relief